# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I know what caused this error, I explicitly removed the header from axios call to check if the code can handle the error.  But my question is I have a catch block in place, but I'm still getting this -> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection

```
const getUser1 = () => {
   userService.getUser1().then((res) => {
       setId(res.data._id);
      return Promise.resolve();
    }).catch((error) => Promise.reject(error));
  };

  const getUserComments = () => {
   commentsService.getUserComments(‘user1’).then((res) => {
    setComments(res.data)
      return Promise.resolve();
    }).catch((err) => Promise.reject(err));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const onInit = async () => {
      await Promise.all([
        getUser1(),
        getUserComments(),
      ]).catch((ex) => console.log(ex));
    };
    onInit();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this version:

```js
  const getUser1 = async () => {
    try{
      const {data} = await userService.getUser1()
      setId(data._id);
    }
    catch(err){
      throw new Error(err)
    }
   };
 
   const getUserComments = async () => {
    try{
      const {data} = await commentsService.getUserComments(‘user1’)
      setComments(data)
    }
    catch(err){
      throw new Error(err)
    }
   };

   const init = useCallback(async () =>{
      try{
      return await Promise.all([
        getUser1(),
        getUserComments(),
      ])
      }
      catch(err){
        console.error(err)
      }
   }, [])
 
   useEffect(() => {
     init();
   }, [init]);
```